# How can I migrate the pull requests from one Git Server to another Git Server for a repository?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am using below commands to migrate the repository from one Git server to another.I am able to move the tags but unable to move the pull requests.

**git clone --bare https://github.forEx.myRepositoryUrl**

**git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Example/myRepositoryUrl.git**

**git push --all**

**git push --tags**

Comment: The *actual pull requests*, like issues and other GitHub-only items, are not stored in the *repository* and cannot be migrated. The *commits that went into PRs* are stored in the repository, using the GitHub-specific names that are in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72782282/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

You would need at least to fetch the `pull/` namespace in which those PR branches are stored.

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://github.forEx.myRepositoryUrl
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

And create local branches for you to push back to the new repository.

```bash
git fetch
git for-each-ref refs/heads/pull/* --format='%(refname:short)'| \
  while read ref; do \
    git switch pull/${ref} \
  done
```

That might now however transfer the actual pull request item, with its comments and validation.