# Migrate/duplicate git repository with all remote branches, pull requests and tags

Tags: git, github, repository, repo

Is there any way to migrate/duplicate the repository from the GitHub Account-X to the GitHub account-Y account, so that all branches, pull requests and tags are present in the new location? I have a reasonably quick way to migrate all branches with tags, but I don't know how to transfer pull requests with it. I need PR, due to the history.

Commands which I used to migrate branches and tags

```
git clone --mirror OLD_REPO_URL
cd new-cloned-project
mkdir .git
mv * .git
git config --local --bool core.bare false
git reset --hard HEAD
git remote add XX DESTINATION
git push --all XX
git push --tags XX
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72782282/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+migrate+pull+requests

Comment: The actual pull requests are stored in a separate database (not part of Git) and therefore Git cannot copy them. The *commits* for the PRs are stored in Git.